# Downloading PDF from API URL

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am working in Angular project, where i have to show pdf file to the user after successful login.

the pdf file came from api url, i dont know how to download and show that into app, because when i run api the file is downloading instead of viewing.

can anyone help me to solve this issue. i tried cordova file transfer plugin too.

API link
[PDF API](https://sandbox.mcdanielsupply.co/miko/get_handbook_binary?token=cd192920-f80e-0137-abe8-0cc47a343ef4)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can achieve it using [ng2-PDF-viewer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-pdf-viewer). Here you can show PDF from API to the user. Live demo is here. https://vadimdez.github.io/ng2-pdf-viewer/

Paste your API URL into side bar 'Set URL of PDF file' to see your file for demo.

Complete integration is provided on the library page.

Comment: thanks for your idea, i already tried this. problem is we can only use the url with .pdf extension for the 'src' property of pdf viewer. we cannot pass the api url.

Comment: @saravanakumar I actually used your API URL only for loading PDF file. see in the screenshot https://prnt.sc/ummrbt . I recommend you to recheck.

Comment: i tried in my angular application, while running that app in real device, that pdf file was downloaded. i dont know how its works for you. okay let me check once again. thanks for your answers

Comment: it will work for android lower versions? because i am using cordova based angular application. my app will work on android kitkat 4.4 & android 5 lolipop versions.

Comment: thanks @shabbir Dhangot its working now. thanks a lot